# Record all the changing values of a range on excel sheet 1 to sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

The below code records the changing values of cell A1 onto sheet 2. I need something like this code that records all the changing values onto sheet2 of range "A1:E1" from sheet 1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

With Worksheets("Sheet2")

 .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You want  value from `A1` or all range value from `Column A" ??

Comment: I want all values from A1  B1 C1 D1 AND E1

Answer (score 1):

I will use `copy` method in your case, by copy all value from `sheet1` to the next row in `sheet2`, please try and see:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E1").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lastrow, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for replying :) the cells from A1 to E1 contain formula and their values change according to that formula , your code is working but when the values in cells change,  it's pasting zero in sheet 2 not the actual changed values

Comment: I see, I didnot know your `sheet1`  range contain formula, anyway glad to know you solve it

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your original code so the destination on `Sheet2` spans columns `A:E`.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")

       .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Resize(,5).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E1").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Record Row Change with the `Worksheet_Calculate` Event

- Copy the following codes into the appropriate modules.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Public RRC_OLD_DATA As Variant
Public Const RRC_ROW_ADDRESS As String = "A1:E1"
Public Const RRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"

Sub RecordRowChange(ByVal sws As Worksheet)
    
    Const dwsName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirstColumn As String = "A"
    
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = sws.Range(RRC_ROW_ADDRESS).Value
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(sData, 2)
    
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To cCount
        If sData(1, c) <> RRC_OLD_DATA(1, c) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    
    If c <= cCount Then
        Dim drg As Range
        With sws.Parent.Worksheets(dwsName)
            Set drg = .Cells(.Rows.Count, dFirstColumn).End(xlUp) _
                .Offset(1).Resize(, cCount)
        End With
        drg.Value = sData
        RRC_OLD_DATA = sData
    End If

End Sub
```

**`Sheet1` Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    RecordRowChange Me
End Sub
```

**`ThisWorkbook` Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    RRC_OLD_DATA = Me.Worksheets(RRC_SHEET_NAME).Range(RRC_ROW_ADDRESS).Value
End Sub
```